# TinyMCE - mceInsertContent without converting html to entites

Tags: javascript, tinymce, entities

I am writing a plugin that will allow me to add prepared html partials to my editor.

My problem is that when I run mceInsertContent command it automatically converts my < > brackets into entities.

I wanted to change that by setting entity_encondig to "named" and defining entites as null, bu it does not help. It looks like in named mode it still converts all entites that are being converted in "raw" mode.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding

I am looking for solution for this one.